# Rps is very low compare to given number of users

Tags: performance, testing, load, performance-testing, locust

I am new in load testing , For understanding the statistics generated by locust , I give very low load to an API, See my below snapshot, there is only 1 user run against given API and it finish its process within milliseconds but my RPS is showing 0 . I am expecting RPS value as 1 because the request able to finish within one second.

[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ2Aa.png)

Comment: We'd need to know more about your code. What's your task like and what is your `wait_time` set to?

Answer (score 0):

See my code below and please note that I am not giving any wait_time in my code and it is a very simple code which I wrote.

[Main code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Iam.png)

[config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTfuO.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).